# getJSON failing on Weather API

Tags: javascript

So im using the Weather API found here:
https://openweathermap.org/

Im getting some very confusing results when trying to make a sample weather application on jsfiddle (and eventually moving it over to code-pen)

https://jsfiddle.net/matt40413/buLuvgcL/1/

^^ Example here.

So here is the weird thing, in my example it will work if I replace the "url" with a string that's a literal url. IE:`"http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1"` (This is just a sample)

HOWEVER, I have to change it to https for it to work (the url itself). BUT if you do https on your browser it will fail.

regardless it fails when I try to pass `url` into the getJSON function always, whether i change it to https or not. I do get the URL and going to the URL will return JSON data but on jsfiddle it says

> Object {error: "Please use POST request"}

I haven't gotten it to work on codepen.io either without using "samples". Any ideas at what could be happening?

Comment: `BUT if you do https on your browser it will fail` - clearly `openweathermap.org` are numpties who have used an idiot to configure HTTPS - seems you need a) a valid api key, and b) http not https

Comment: The problem actually ended up being the chrome browser..not sure why. Location was enabled and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being with Chrome. Location was enabled on chrome but yet it was blocking the location service from codepen. Not sure why.

Switching to firefox fixed the issue.